# Only one user got error in peoplepicker: System.InvalidOperationException: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined

Tags: people-picker

We are using sp2010. We have a sp site. There are some libraries. There is one user which got an error when he search on a user in people picker. When he clicks on ok he got this error :

[image]

uls error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not
>   defined.    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ToXmlQualifiedName(String
>   value, Boolean decodeName)     at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read1_Object(Boolean
>   isNullable, Boolean checkType)     at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read2_DictionaryEntry(Boolean
>   checkType)     at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read3_ArrayOfDictionaryEntry()

Answer (score 1):

fixed by my self. I checked the checkbox of enable compatibility mode for intranet sites. Now this sharepoint site is running under compatibility mode and the people picker is working fine.